# what http response code when ADFS endpoint be called on browser

Tags: http, active-directory, adfs

In ADFS server we have endpoint url, what will be result when we browse for endpoint url?, am new to ADFS.

Comment: HTTP 401 Challenge - that will be the result. Install and test, then ask questions!

Comment: Endpoint url of what service?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether the endpoint is for passive or active clients and whether you use http/https. You'll get a different status code and errors accordingly if the request hitting the AD FS server doesn't get what it expects.

If the intention is to test whether AD FS is functional, then please use the federation metadata endpoints as per the end of the http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-troubleshooting-things-to-check(v=ws.10).aspx article.